# Recommended way to use Rails view helpers in a presentation class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been researching the 'recommended' way to use Rails view helpers (e.g. `link_to`, `content_tag`) in a plain ruby class, such as a presenter. It seems there's very little information on this front and I wanted to get an idea of what the Stack community thought.

So, the options we have are.. (note I'm using Rails 4, and am less concerned about older versions)

**Include the required modules manually**

This is probably the cleanest way, since only the helpers needed are included. However I have found this method to not work in some cases, as the usual view context provided in plain Rails helpers is configured for the current request. `url_for` wouldn't know about the current request for example, so the host might not match.

```
class MyPresenter
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper

    def wrapped_link
        content_tag :div, link_to('My link', root_url)
    end
end
```

**Use `ActionController::Base.helpers`**

Since Rails 3, `ActionController::Base` has included a `helpers` method to access the current view context. I believe the view context provided by this method is configured as it would be in a rails helper, but I might be wrong. There's not really any documentation about this which seems worrying, but it does work quite well in practice.

```
class MyPresenter
    def wrapped_link
        h.content_tag :div, h.link_to('My link', h.root_url)
    end

    protected

    def h
        ActionController::Base.helpers
    end
end
```

I believe this view context can also be mixed in with `include`, but the rails view helpers have hundreds of methods and it feels dirty to include them all indiscriminately.

**Inject the view context when calling the presenter**

Finally, we could just pass the view context to the class when it's initialized (or alternatively in a `render` method)

```
class MyPresenter
    attr_accessor :context
    alias_method :h, :context

    def initialize(context)
        @context = context
    end

    def wrapped_link
        h.content_tag :div, h.link_to('My link', h.root_url)
    end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
    def show
        # WARNING - `view_context` in a controller creates an object
        @presenter = MyPresenter.new(view_context) 
    end
end
```

Personally I tend to lean towards the latter two options, but with no definitive answer from the Rails team (that I've been able to find) I felt a bit unsure. Who better to ask than Stack!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with the mix of the second and third option, something like:

```rb
class MyPresenter
  def initialize(helpers)
    @h = helpers
  end

  def wrapped_link
    h.content_tag :div, h.link_to('My link', h.root_url)
  end

  private
  attr_reader :h
end
```

Your second option require all your unit tests to be stubbed as `ActionController::Base.helpers` which maybe isn't a good option and your third option you're using a huge context to access just some methods.

Comment: Good point about stubbing `ActionController::Base.helpers`, I hadn't thought about that. Stylistically this seems like the best route to take, and after a bit of research I think the best (only) `view_context` to use is the one provided by the controller or helper calling the presenter.

Answer (score 2):

I would really make that dependent on what kind of methods you use. If it's just the basics like `content_tag` etc. I would go for the `ActionController::Base.helpers` way. It is also possible to call some helpers directly, e.g. for paths inside models I almost always use something along the lines of `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.comment_path`.

For controller-specific stuff the third option might be useful, but personally the "pure" way seems nicer. Draper has an interesting approach too: They save the `view_context` for the current request and then delegate the calls to `h`-helpers to it: https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/master/lib/draper/view_context.rb

It really is just a matter of preference. I would never include all helpers at once, as you already said. But the second option is quite nice if you want to build the presentation layer yourself without using a gem like Draper or Cells.

Comment: Thanks Rudolf, I'd looked into Draper too. Interesting they also use the controller `view_context`, though it seems like they've had plenty of trouble with this in the past - https://github.com/drapergem/draper/issues/124